# Dual-Core Hyperthreading: Should I use 4 threads or 3 or 2?

Tags: multithreading, hyperthreading

If you're spawning multiple threads (or processes) concurrently, is it better to spawn as many as the number of *physical* processors or the number of *logical* processors, assuming the task is CPU-bound? Or is it better to do something in between (say, 3 threads)?

Does the performance depend on the kind of instructions that are getting executed (say, would non-local memory access be much different from cache hits)? If so, in which cases is it better to take advantage of hyperthreading?

---

Update:

The reason I'm asking is, I remember reading somewhere that if you have as many tasks as the number of virtual processors, tasks on the same physical core can sometimes starve some CPU resources and prevent each other from getting as many resources as needed, possibly decreasing performance. That's why I'm wondering if having as many threads as virtual cores is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance depends on a huge variety of factors.  Most tasks are not strictly CPU bound, since even if all of the data is in memory it is usually not on-board in the processor cache.  I have seen examples (like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx)) where memory access patterns can dramatically change the performance profile of a given 'parallel' process.

In short, there is no perfect number for all situations.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are pretty good that you will see a performance improvement running 2 threads per core with HyperThreading enabled. Jobs that *appear* to be entirely CPU bound usually aren't, and HyperThreading can extract a few "extra" cycles out of the occasional interrupt or context switch.

On the other hand, with a core iX processor that has Turbo Boost, you might actually do better running 1 thread per core to encourage the CPU to overclock itself.

At work, we routinely run many-core servers at full CPU doing various kinds of calculation for days at a time. A while back we measured the performance difference with and without HT. We found that on average, with HyperThreading, and running twice as many jobs at once, we could complete the same amount of jobs about 10% faster than than without HyperThreading.

Assume that 2 × cores is a good place to start, **but the bottom line is: measure!**

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out Turbo Boost feature... I have it on my own CPU but I hadn't ever thought of how that could affect part of the equation.

Comment: There's a relationship between whether or not you get a performance improvement with HyperThreading, and it relates to the fact that cache sizes are halved - if your cache hit rates are high enough, then the loss of cache size doesn't cancel out (or worse) the gain from having two hardware threads.

Answer (score 2):

I remember info that hyperthreading can give you up to 30% of performance boost. in general you'd better to treat them as 4 different cores. of course in some specific circumstances (e.g. having the same long running task bound to each core) you can divide your processing better taking into account that some cores are just logical ones

more info about hyperthreading itself [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology/)

Comment: +1 Interesting... I'd read other Intel documentation on HT but this one's different and has a lot more info; thanks!

Comment: Link is 404 now.

Answer (score 2):

Using Hyperthreading to run two threads on the same core, when both threads have similar memory access patterns but access disjoint data structures, would be very roughly equivalent to running them on two separate cores each with half the cache.  If the memory-access patterns are such that half the cache would be sufficient to prevent thrashing, performance may be good.  If the memory-access patterns are such that halving the cache induces thrashing, there may be a ten-fold performance hit (implying one would have been much better off without hyperthreading).

On the other hand, there are some situations where hyperthreading may be a huge win.  If many threads will all be reading and writing the same shared data using lock-free data structures, and all threads must see a consistent view of the data, trying to run threads on disjoint processor may cause thrashing since only one processor at a time may have read-write access to any given cache line; running such a threads on two cores may take longer than running only one at a time.  Such cache arbitration is not required, however, when a piece of data is accessed by multiple threads on a single core.  In those cases, hyperthreading can be a huge win.

Unfortunately, I don't know any way to give the scheduler any "hints" to suggest that some threads should share a core when possible, while others should run separately when possible.

Comment: You can set processor affinity for a thread, that's better than a hint.

Comment: @ChrisO: Yes, but a real "hinting" mechanism would be able to say "thread X should share the same core as thread Y if possible", while still allowing the scheduler to decide *which* core they will share at any given moment.

Comment: Yes, I get it now, the hint would be in fact be better than hardcoded core #.

Comment: @ChrisO: I find it really odd and irksome that there isn't widespread support for applications to specify their preferred threading scenarios, given that (1) there are cases where hyperthreading may be almost twice as fast as single-threading, and using two cores may be many times slower; (2) there are cases where using two cores may be almost twice as fast as single-threading, and hyperthreading may be many times slower; (3) application authors may have a pretty good idea if applications would likely be anywhere near either extreme.

Answer (score 1):

HT allows a boost of approximately 10-30% for *mostly* cpu-bound tasks that use the extra virtual cores.  Although these tasks may seem CPU-bound, unless they are custom made assembly, they will usually suffer from IO waits between RAM and local cache.  This allows one thread running on a physical HT-enabled core to work while the other thread is waiting for IO.  This does come with a disadvantage though, as two threads share the same cache/bus, which will result in less resources each which may cause both threads to pause while waiting for IO.

In the last case, running a single thread will decrease the maximum simultaneous theoretical processing power(by 10-30%) in favor of running a single thread without the slowdown of cache thrashing which may be very significant in some applications.

Choosing which cores to use is just as important as choosing how many threads to run.  If each thread is CPU-bound for roughly the same duration it is best to set the affinity such that threads using mostly different resources find themselves on different physical cores and threads using common resources be grouped to the same physical cores(different virtual core) so that common resources can be used from the same cache without extra IO wait.

Since each program has different CPU-usage characteristics and cache thrashing may or may not be a major slowdown(it usually is) it is impossible to determine what the ideal number of threads should be without profiling first.  One last thing to note is that the OS/Kernel will also require some CPU and cache space.  It is usually ideal to keep a single (physical)core set aside for the OS if real-time latency is required on CPU-bound threads so as to avoid sharing cache/cpu resources.  If threads are often waiting for IO and cache thrashing is not an issue, or if running a real-time OS specifically designed for the application, you can skip this last step.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers already give lots of excellent info.  But, one more point to consider is that the SIMD unit is shared between logical cores on the same die.  So, if you are running threads with SSE code, do you run them on all 4 logical cores, or just spawn 2 threads (assuming you have two chips)?  For this odd case, best to profile with your app.