# OHC Caching in Java

Tags: java, caching

I am learning about Java off-heap cache and I use OHC cache. I found out about the source code of OHC and it contains methods that I don't know what they are used for. Hope someone can explain it to me, thanks.

```
        int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); // my CPU = 4 

        segmentCount = roundUpToPowerOf2(cpus * 2, 1 << 30);

        capacity = Math.min(cpus * 16, 64) * 1024 * 1024;

static int roundUpToPowerOf2(int number, int max) {
    return number >= max ? max : (number > 1) ? Integer.highestOneBit((number - 1) << 1) : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize lock contention, OHC splits the entire cache into 'segments' so that only if two entries hash to the same segment must one operation wait for the other. This is something like table-level locking in a relational database.

- The meaning of `cpus` is clear enough.
- Default `segmentCount` is the smallest power of `2` larger than twice the CPU count. For the logic of doubling the CPU count for throughput optimization, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771384.
- `capacity` is the total storable data size in the cache. The default is 16MB per core. This is probably designed to correspond with [CPU cache sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#History), though presumably a user would have an idea of their application's actual capacity needs and would very likely be configuring this value and not using the default anyway.

The actual `roundUpToPowerOf2` can be explained as follows:
Do not go above `max`, nor below `1`. (I suppose it's up to the caller to assure that max is itelf a power of two or, it's ok for it not to be in this case.) In betweeen: To get a power of two, we want an `int` comprised of a single one bit (or all zeros). `Integer#highestOneBit` gives such a number with the turned on bit being the leftmost turned on bit in its argument. So we need to provide it with a number with whose leftmost turned on bit is:

- the same as `number` if it is already a power of two, or
- one position to the left of `number`'s leftmost one bit.

Calculating `number - 1` before left shifting is for the first case. If `number` is a power of two, then left shifting as-is would give us the *next* power of two, which isn't what we want. For the second case, the `number` (or it's value subtracted by `1`) left shifted turns on the next larger bit, then `Integer#highestOneBit` effectively blanks out all of the bits to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's the best thing for me.